# Servo wont work with LED code!

Tags: arduino-uno, led, servo

I'm basically trying to combine my servo code and my LED code but whenever I add my servo code the LED refuses to turn on at all.
I am super new to arduino sorry if this doesn't make any sense!

```
Servo myservo; 

const int pushbutton_PIN = 2; 
const int POT_PIN = A0;
const int LED_PIN = 3; 

int pos = 0;   
int buttonState = 0; 
int lastbuttonState = 0; 
int analogValue = 0; 
int lightState = false; 
int brightness = 0;

void setup() { 
  myservo.attach(9); 
  pinMode(pushbutton_PIN, INPUT); 
  pinMode(POT_PIN, INPUT); 
  pinMode(LED_PIN, OUTPUT); 
  Serial.begin(9600); 
}

void loop(){
  light();
  servo();
  }

void servo(){
        for (pos = 0; pos <= 180; pos += 1) { 
    // in steps of 1 degree
    myservo.write(pos);             
    delay(15);                       
  }
  for (pos = 180; pos >= 0; pos -= 1) { 
    myservo.write(pos);              
    delay(15);  
  }
}
 
void light() {
      buttonState = digitalRead(pushbutton_PIN);
  if (buttonState != lastbuttonState) { 
    if (buttonState == HIGH) {
      delay(300);
      lightState = true;
      light_on();
    }
  }
  lastbuttonState = buttonState;
}
  

void light_on() {
  while (lightState == true) {
    analogValue = analogRead(POT_PIN);
    brightness = map(analogValue, 0, 1023, 0, 255);
    analogWrite(LED_PIN, brightness);
    buttonState = digitalRead(pushbutton_PIN);
    if (buttonState != lastbuttonState) { 
      if (buttonState == HIGH) {
        lightState = false;
        delay(300);
        analogWrite(LED_PIN, LOW);
        loop();
      }
    }
    lastbuttonState = buttonState;
  }
}
```

Comment: I think your problem is the blocking code. While your servo code run, the LED isn't handled in any way. To do multiple this at the same time (like controlling a servo, checking a button and controlling an LED, you actually need to do these this sequentially in very fast succession, basically only doing something, when it is time to do so, otherwise going further to the next thing. No delay calls (thats just busy waiting). Please look at tutorials about `millis()`and the `BlinkWithoutDelay` example, that comes with the Arduino IDE. It is very important coding principle for microcontrollers.

Comment: Common issue with PWM and Servo when it doesn't work is that used PWM pin is on the same Timer taken over by Servo library. But it's usualy using Timer1 and pin 3 is on timer 2, so it might not be issue in this case

Comment: Each call to your servo() function takes well over 5 seconds (_5.4s, for the delay() calls alone!_), during which nothing else - testing the button, f/ex - is being done. Seconding @chrisl 's suggestion to review the `BlinkWithoutDelay` example. Also search Arduino StackExchange for "non-blocking".

Comment: To add on to Chris's comment there is a really good sticky post on the arduino forum in the project guidance section which deals with this exact issue for newbies. I think it's called: doing several things at the same time

Comment: is there any reason why you are moving the servo in small steps?

Comment: @chrisl I've looked into what you suggested and I think I've figured it out, so thank you! However if I removed my delays for the servo I'm worried my servo will move too fast for what I need it for. Is there a way to slow my servo down without any delay calls?

Comment: Exactly as I wrote: With `millis()` and the principle in the `BlinkWithoutDelay` example. That requires a restructuring of your code.